# Scraping the text from an <href> using javascript and puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape text from a website using javascript, nodejs and puppeteer. I can successfully scrape certain areas of the site, but only for static text on the site.

The last piece of data I want to scrape is the text of an href tag. However, when I use the same code that I used successfully for the scraping the text, I get the incorrect information for the href. Here is my text scraping code:

```
const [name] = await page.$x('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]');
const txt = await name.getProperty('textContent');
const Name = await txt.jsonValue();
```

This code above correctly returns a person's name from the site. To get the correct return above I am using Copy XPath on the target site.

The last piece of data I want to scrape looks like this:

```
<a href="/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=2395775">
              <span class="listing-cat">
                <span class="icon icon-person"></span>
                PROFESSOR
              </span>
              <span class="listing-name">
                <span class="main">lastName, firstName</span>
                <span class="sub">Company, Department</span>
              </span>
            </a>
```

All I want to scrape is the actual text of the first line, the href "/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=2395775". But using the code shown earlier I get the incorrect results returned. I think my error is that I need to modify the puppeteer commands because I am trying to scrape text from an href versus normal static text.

Here is a link to the GitHub for puppeteer: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

Appreciate any help.

Comment: what's the code you use to get href? what error do you get?